# bash - Send string to Cursor

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a script will print a string to the location of my cursor whether it be a web form, a word doc, whatever.

Basically I am creating a barcode scanning script that will run in the background. I want to be able to scan a barcode the script will then read the code which will be text pull a substring out of it and then print that substring where my cursor is. I am using the QR code reader zbar. I tried to do it with the program Crikey but after it prints the string out it issues the enter command which I do not want and I could not find a way to make it not do that.

Is there another way to go about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `xdotool`:

```
xdotool type "hello world"
```

This will simulate the user typing "hello world" on the keyboard for the current X11 session.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xclip and xdotool

xclip to places you string in the clipboard,
xdotool to simulate a click + "ctrl v".

```
echo Hello | xclip; 
xdotool click 1; 
xdotool key "ctrl+v"
```